# Trouble with printing (nested loops) (beginner level) (probably)

Tags: python

I'm having trouble separating the classes of the students (eg p01, p02, p03). Any suggestions?

```
p01 = [['Amber', 'A'], ['Bob', 'A'], ['Chad', 'F']]

p02 = [['Wesley', 'B+'], ['Joel', 'A'], ['Victor', 'C']]

p03 = [['Pamela', 'D+'], ['Joseph', 'A'], ['Sam', 'B+']]]

group_list = [p01, p02, p03]
group_name = ['p01', 'p02', 'p03']

print("{:<5s} {:<8s} {:<5s}\n".format("Group", "Student", "Grade"))

for i in range(len(group_name)):                  #something is wrong here
    for student in group_list[i]:
        name = student[0]
        grade = student[1]
        print("{:<5s} {:<8s} {:<5s}".format(group_name[i], name, grade))
```

(I'm not sure what to add to ensure the classes are separated)

Expected output

```
p01   Amber    A
p01   Bob      A
p01   Chad     F

p02   Wesley   B+
p02   Joel     A
p02   Victor   C

p03   Pamela   D+
p03   Joseph   A
p03   Sam      B+
```

Actual output

```
p01   Amber    A
p01   Bob      A
p01   Chad     F
p02   Wesley   B+
p02   Joel     A
p02   Victor   C
p03   Pamela   D+
p03   Joseph   A
p03   Sam      B+
```

Comment: You can add a ```print("\n")``` after nested for loop

Comment: As an aside, you can use `for grname, students in zip(group_name, group_list):` to iterate over both lists simultaneously without explicit indexing.

Comment: @Sujay `print()` is sufficient; with no arguments, it will print an empty string, followed by the default value `'\n'` of its `end` keyword argument.

Comment: Better yet, use a `dict` like `groups = dict(zip(group_name, group_list))`. Then your loops become `for group_name, group in groups.items(): for name, student in group: ...`. No `i` needed.

Comment: The individual names `p01`, `p02`, and `p03` should never exist; define the list/dict directly.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a `\n` character:

```
for i in range(len(group_name)):                  #something is wrong here
    for student in group_list[i]:
        name = student[0]
        grade = student[1]
        print("{:<5s} {:<8s} {:<5s}".format(group_name[i], name, grade))
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Most Welcome! @KelvenLim ;)